# How to add some rows in Excel which only span about 5 columns

Tags: excel

I want to add some rows in an existing spreadsheet in Excel but only to span about 5 columns, is it possible and how?

Grahame
It doesnt meet your quality standards but it is as clear as i can make it.

Comment: Edit your question and put some sample data and expected output. Then brief what you want.

Comment: Do you mean you want to insert cells, rather than entire rows?

Answer (score 0):

you can. Insert cells and move cells according to your needs.
See pictures

[image]

[image]